# How do I convert date/time from one timezone to another?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, date-format

Is it possible to convert date/time from **EST** (America/New_York) into **UTC**, given string in format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`?

*Example:*

```
getUTCfromNY("2015-11-01 01:00:00", "NY");
```

should output:

```
GMT Time: 2015-11-01 06:00:00
```

**Edit**

Between the two results below, which one should you take?

`getUTCfromNY("2015-11-01 01:00:00", "NY")` GMT Time: 2015-11-01 **06**:00:00

`getUTCfromNY("2015-11-01 01:00:00", "NY")` GMT Time: 2015-11-01 **05**:00:00